# Is there a way to increase timeout for 'NFCMifareTag.SendMiFareCommand()'?

Tags: ios, mifare, core-nfc

I'm working on an NFC app for R&W operations on an NFC tag.

All R&W operations work fine with the 'SendMiFareCommand()' API, however there's a special command for 'password authentication' feature where it fails with a timeout, may be because the NFC tag is not responding in time.

This issue is not observed every time, so I'm sure about the command I'm sending nd how its response is to be processed. Moreover, this issue appears more frequently on iPhone 12 & 13 than older ones, may be because they changed something at the NFC lower layer.

Anyway, Android allows adjusting timeout which is usually done before sending any command, so that it gets enough time to respond and the session remains active. It's typically done as -
mifareTag.Timeout = timeout_value_ms;

Can this be done for iOS? I could not find much in their API documentation.

Comment: I’ve been searching but I haven’t found any way.